# How to create boarders in a Table in SummerNote

Tags: editor, summernote

When inserting a table into the editing area of Summernote editor, how do I outline the boarders of the table sections with a line? For example - the way Word does it's tables.

All help appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a picture of what excatly you want to do , and do you have access to edit css attributes or not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you open Microsoft Word and insert a box, you will see that the boxes have boarders around them.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Microsoft Word and insert a box, you will see that the boxes have boarders around them.  SummerNote does display a very very faint line around the boxes of the table but on a white background it's impossible to see.  I would like to draw darker and even thicker lines around the boxes.  I would like to provide an example from Word but can't see a way to do it.  Yes, I think I can edit CSS given some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Summernote calls tableClassName when table is created via jquery's addClass method. So I used that to inject my jquery code like this:

```
<script>
$('#xyz').summernote({
    tableClassName: function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('table table-bordered')

        .attr('cellpadding', 12)
        .attr('cellspacing', 0)
        .attr('border', 1)
        .css('borderCollapse', 'collapse');

        $(this).find('td')
        .css('borderColor', '#ccc')
        .css('padding', '15px');
    },
});
</script>
```

[Link for Information](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2391)